# How to Get Information about completed WEBGISDR Process

Tags: arcgis-enterprise

Using ArcGIS Enterprise 10.9.1 can some one please let me know where and how I can check the status of running `webgisdr`?
I also need to get the total process time of the completed `webgisdr` process or any other information regarding the `webgisdr`?